# Why there is a space around div

Tags: css

Within the `td` I have four `div`. But I don't know how there is a little bit of margin like space created. And I can't seem to remove it.

If this is the behaviour of `inline-block`, then how to override this behaviour?

```css
.box{
  width: 25%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<table style='width: 100%;'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class='box'></div>
      <div class='box'></div>
      <div class='box'></div>
      <div class='box'></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: a simple google search and you got it ... https://www.google.com/search?ei=lLM0W4qLF8miU9v4vdAP&q=space+inline+block&oq=space+inline+block&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i30k1j0i5i30k1l2j0i8i30k1l3.1929.2721.0.3016.2.2.0.0.0.0.190.347.0j2.2.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.2.345...0i13k1j0i13i30k1j0i13i5i30k1j0i8i13i30k1.0.393edJU6ZSw ... you may notice this is the 2nd frequent question asked on CSS

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Because there is **white-space** between the `divs` (line-break and spaces). ;)

```css
.box {
  width: 25%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

td {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<table style='width: 100%;'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class='box'></div>
      <div class='box'></div>
      <div class='box'></div>
      <div class='box'></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -3):

you can use float left instead of display inline block i think this is the best and simple to apply

```css
.box{
  width: 25%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<table style='width: 100%;'>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class='box'></div>
      <div class='box'></div>
      <div class='box'></div>
      <div class='box'></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```